# Shade a Range on the Y-Axis

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

When graphing with RRDTool, I have added two VRULEs. I'm graphing temperature, and I would like to have the area between them shaded in on the graph. Does RRDTool have any option like this? I've perused https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph_graph.en.html and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, though you need to do a little trick to achieve it.  The Routers2 software uses this trick to highlight Working Hours during the time window.

In order to do this, you create a dummy `CDEF` that returns a time series that is `+INF` during the highlighted window, and 0 elsewhere.  Then, you graph this as an `AREA`, either before your lines, or after (with transparentcy).

The trick is that the `CDEF` has to be based on a `DEF`, though it can throw away the data and then calculate based on the `TIME` value instead.

For example (simplified for clarity);

```
rrdtool graph output.png \
    DEF:x=file.rrd:ds:AVERAGE \
    CDEF:bg=x,POP,0,INF,TIME,$mintime,$maxtime,LIMIT,UN,IF \
    AREA:bg#ff808080 \
    LINE:x#00ff00:Value \
    VRULE:$mintime#ff8080 \
    VRULE:$maxtime#ff8080
```

This will draw a line (in green) for the data; behind it is a seethrough pink highlight between times `$mintime` and `$maxtime`, and at these two times, a red `VRULE` is overlaid.

Note how the `CDEF` throws away the initial value of x, and instead  uses `LIMIT` to tell if the sample time is in the range, subsequently using `IF` to give a value of either 0 or `INF` depending on the result.  This is then used for the `AREA` that forms the highlight.

Instead of using a set `$mintime` and `$maxtime`, you could instead use the value of `LTIME` (which takes into account your local timezone offset) to calculate the actual time of day, and highlight between 9am and 5pm M-F.  This is the trick used by Routers2 to enable it to highlight multiple areas for working hours.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve! I'll check out the rrdtool man page tomorrow so I can understand more of what's going on. Glad to see it's possible. BTW, great name -- mine is Stephen.

Comment: For the really uninitiated, $mintime and $maxtime are seconds since epoch.